# I wants to import eclipse theme file to zend studio how can i do it?

Tags: eclipse, zend-studio

hi there i wants to import theme.xml file from eclipse to Zend studion, can any guys suggest me how can i do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To install the colour preferences:

Download one of the below packages

http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/?list=all&page=3

and extract the contents to a temporary directory

**Backup** your current preferences by going to

File -> Export -> General -> Preferences.

Follow the instructions from there to create a preferences file. Make sure you choose “Export all”.

**To install the colour preferences Go to**

File -> Import -> General -> Preferences and select the Obsidian/eclipse.epf file. Click “Finish”